# What is fetchKnowingCookie middleware used for in the react starter kit?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, react-starter-kit

Looking through the createHelpers.js code in the react starter kit, I see that it's creating a grapqlRequest and a fetchKnowingCookie method in the middleware.

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/feature/redux/src/store/createHelpers.js

What exactly is this doing?  Is it adding a cookie header to server rendered fetch requests?

I see that it's also passing in the functions into the middleware via `thunk.withExtraArgument`, what does that extra line do?  Does it mean the fetch with cookies function becomes available from redux async actions?

```
import fetch from '../core/fetch';

function createGraphqlRequest(fetchKnowingCookie) {
  return async function graphqlRequest(query, variables) {
    const fetchConfig = {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
      credentials: 'include',
    };
    const resp = await fetchKnowingCookie('/graphql', fetchConfig);
    if (resp.status !== 200) throw new Error(resp.statusText);
    return await resp.json();
  };
}

function createFetchKnowingCookie({ cookie }) {
  if (!process.env.BROWSER) {
    return (url, options = {}) => {
      const isLocalUrl = /^\/($|[^/])/.test(url);

      // pass cookie only for itself.
      // We can't know cookies for other sites BTW
      if (isLocalUrl && options.credentials === 'include') {
        const headers = {
          ...options.headers,
          cookie,
        };
        return fetch(url, { ...options, headers });
      }

      return fetch(url, options);
    };
  }

  return fetch;
}

export default function createHelpers(config) {
  const fetchKnowingCookie = createFetchKnowingCookie(config);
  const graphqlRequest = createGraphqlRequest(fetchKnowingCookie);

  return {
    fetch: fetchKnowingCookie,
    graphqlRequest,
    history: config.history,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is injecting a modified version of `fetch` into the thunk middleware being applied to the store.

`react-starter-kit` is using `node-fetch` to handle `fetch` calls on the server. Unfortunately, `node-fetch` [doesn't support cookies](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/master/LIMITS.md).

Every time a user makes a request to the server, a new store is configured using [`req.headers.cookie`](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/feature/redux/src/server.js#L93-L97). That cookie object will then be used in any `fetch` requests made by thunks in your application, getting around the `node-fetch` limitation.